# Lightning Web Component Design Tokens? CSS in experience builder. Can't figure this one out

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, design, web

I'll start with a TL;DR
Need to pass a value from Experience Builder into CSS. E.g. if someone chooses black on the property type of Color, the value well be passed to a custom CSS class. I have tried the below with no success.

```
.custom-class { var(--propertyName); }
```

Really struggling with this one. I need to allow admins to change the color of buttons in a lightning web component that is being used as a community hero via Experience Builder.

All sings are pointing to the need of using an Aura design token, but I have seen a few hints of a recent update of this being supported in LWCs.

My background is in web dev, so I have a solid understanding of the core concept, but how in the world do I get the TargetConfig property type color to show in the Experience builder for the button?

I am passing string values to other pieces of the LWC, so that is working, but I can't figure out how to pass a string or any value to the CSS of the LWC.

Edit: thanks for the markdown edit Brian.

Code

js-meta.xml

```
<property name="secondaryButtonColor" type="Color" default="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" label="Secondary button color"/>
```

js

```
@api secondaryButtonColor;
```

css

```
.button {
background-color:var(--secondaryButtonColor);
}
```

html

```
<a href="#" class="button">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass variabled to CSS file from javascript. You have to depend on javascript to apply styles at run time. Below is how you can do it:

HTML:

```
<button style={btnBackground}>My Btn</button>
```

JS:

```
@api
secondaryButtonColor = 'yellow';

get btnBackground() {
    return `background:${this.secondaryButtonColor}`;
}
```

Whatever you select from app builder for `secondaryButtonColor` will be passed to change color. [Here is the playground example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/z6qmM23BY/2/edit)

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is working! I want to be sure that I am understanding the process behind this. Looks like I am creating an inline style element in the HTML that JavaScript is then using a getter to return the property value. Does that sound correct? Man, thanks again!

Comment: yes right.......

Comment: Thank you. We are working with complex customer solutions and will keep Groundswell in mind.